# Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I wrote my java application via Eclipse Luna on Windows.
And It is maven project.
I exported `runnable jar file` with `Extract required libraries into generated JAR` option.

And then, copied and ran via java8 openjdk `java8 -jar chatserver.jar` on linux server(EC2 Amazon Linux).

However console outputs just error.

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile chatserver.jar

Here is my menifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: {serviceDomain}.chat.ChatServer

Name: org/aspectj/lang/
Implementation-Title: org.aspectj.tools
Implementation-Version: 1.8.2
Bundle-Name: AspectJ Runtime
Bundle-Version: 1.8.2
Specification-Vendor: aspectj.org
Specification-Title: AspectJ Runtime Classes 
Bundle-Copyright: (C) Copyright 1999-2001 Xerox Corporation, 2002 Palo
   Alto Research Center, Incorporated (PARC), 2003-2009 Contributors. 
  All Rights Reserved.
Specification-Version: 1.8
Implementation-Vendor: aspectj.org
```

How can I export java application correctly, or deploy my appliction easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[vServer Linux - Start jar: Invalid or corrupt jarfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299659/vserver-linux-start-jar-invalid-or-corrupt-jarfile)

I found my answer.

I changed ftp mode to binary then works.