# Jhipster Invalid or corrupt jarfile

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

I am trying to build a jhipster project with the mvn wrapper that is included in the project: `mvnw`, with the command `mvnw -Pdev package`. The war gets built properly, but when I try to execute it (supposed to be executable natively on mac and linux) I get the following error

`CMUTGI-GW-MB:gringotts cmutgi$ ./target/gringotts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /Users/cmutgi/gringotts/target/gringotts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it the same when you run `java -jar target/gringotts-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`?

Comment: yes, I get the same error when I run the command you mentioned

Comment: Then something is corrupting it in your environment when you generate it (maybe an antivirus)? Have you tried to build your war in JHipster devbox? https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32299659/vserver-linux-start-jar-invalid-or-corrupt-jarfile

Comment: I tried building it on a different box (ubuntu, my dev box is mac) it seems to work fine. Not sure what might be going on with my dev box.